# Assemblie.load.getType doesn't work for types with?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a huge like 110000+ line codefile that I'm reading out for some specific types to get information about them.
I get those types from a .json file.

The reading out part is done via reflection (the assembly is in a other solution):

First I load the files into the memory:

```
public static List<Assembly> LoadAssemblies(List<string> loadedPaths)
    {
        foreach (string loadPath in loadedPaths)
        {
            List<AssemblyName> referencedAssemblyNames = Assembly.LoadFrom(loadPath)
                                     .GetReferencedAssemblies()
                                     .Where(a => a.FullName.StartsWith(Constants.NameSpace))
                                     .ToList();
        }
        return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(a => a.FullName.StartsWith(Constants.NameSpace)).ToList();
    }
```

After that I read out the specific Types and its customattributes that I want information about:

```
  public static Dictionary<string, string> GetCustomAttributes(List<Type> streamDesign, List<Type> enums)
    {
        List<PropertyInfo> propertyInfos = new List<PropertyInfo>();
        streamDesign.ForEach(sd => propertyInfos.AddRange(sd.GetProperties().ToList()));

        Dictionary<string, string> dbUsageMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (Type t in enums)
        {

            var property = propertyInfos
                .Where(p => p.PropertyType.FullName != null ? p.PropertyType.FullName.Equals(t.ToString(),
                                        StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) : false)
                .ToList();

            foreach (PropertyInfo p in property)
            {
                var tmp = p.GetCustomAttributes()
                                .Where(a => a is ColumnAttribute)
                                .FirstOrDefault() as ColumnAttribute;
                if (tmp != null)
                {
                    dbUsageMapping.Add(t.ToString(), tmp.Name);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        return dbUsageMapping;
    }
```

The types I get with this one:

```
  public static List<Type> GetStreamDesignTypes(string loadedPath)
        {
            return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(a => a.Location.Equals(loadedPath)).FirstOrDefault().GetTypes().ToList();
        }
```

It works fine for types without "?" -->

```
 public global::JobTemplateType TemplateType {}
```

but types like this -->

```
public global::JobTemplateType? TemplateType {}
```

aren't in there.

Do I have to do something specific to get those types?
And if I search for types with "?", it returns null;

Any ideas?

**Edit:
As requested, original types and the whole code** -->

```
public enum JobTemplateType
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Constant to represent None.
        /// </summary>
        None = 0,

        /// <summary>
        /// Constant to represent a normal job.
        /// </summary>
        Normal = 1,
...
    }
```

The original types are Enums and I want to match the Enums with the CustomAttributes "name" (if exists) to get the occurrences in the database. (for documentation purposes)

```
   public static void start(string path)
{
    // First, I get the Json Data which contains the enums I want Information about and the assembly paths
    /*
     * 
        {
            "Enums":[
                "Common.StreamVersionType",
                "Common.JobTemplateType",
                "Common.JobTemplateType?"
            ],
            "ReturnCodeNames":[
                "Common.JobReturnCodes"
            ],
            "assembliesToLoad":[
                "path.Common.dll",
                "path.Components.dll"
            ],
            "ReturnCodes": true
        }
     */
    DocumentationConfig jsonConfig = FileReader.GetJsonConfig();
    
    // Now I load all the assemblies in the config
    var loadedAssemblies = AssemblieHelper.LoadAssemblies(jsonConfig.AssembliesToLoad);
    // Now I get the types of the huge class I want information about
    var streamDesign = AssemblieHelper.GetStreamDesignTypes(jsonConfig.AssembliesToLoad.Where(a => a.Contains("Business.Components.dll")).FirstOrDefault());
    // After that, I search for the EnumTypes I have in my .json --> this returns the 3 EnumsTypes I want
    var enumTypes = AssemblieHelper.GetTypes(jsonConfig.Enums, loadedAssemblies);
    // with those enumTypes, I want to get all ocurrences in the huge class File where the customeAttributes (i.e. DbName) are stored
    var customAttributes = AssemblieHelper.GetCustomAttributes(streamDesign, enumTypes);
    
    
}
```

And here is the getTypes Function that returns the EnumTypes:

```
public static List<Type> GetTypes(List<string> typeName, List<Assembly> loadedAssemblies)
        {
            List<Type> lEnums = new List<Type>();
            foreach (Assembly assemblie in loadedAssemblies)
            {
                lEnums.AddRange(assemblie.GetTypes().Where(t => typeName.Contains(t.FullName)).ToList());
            }
            return lEnums;
        }
```

**edit2: Example -->**

this one I'm getting:

```
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.StreamRunJob")]
    [global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute()]
    public partial class StreamRunJob : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="TemplateTypeCd", Storage="_TemplateType", DbType="TinyInt NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false, UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
            [global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(Order=59)]
            [GeneratedCodeAttribute("SqlMetal", "")]
            public global::Common.JobTemplateType TemplateType
            {
                get
                {
                    return this._TemplateType;
                }
                set
                {
                    if ((this._TemplateType != value))
                    {
                        this.OnTemplateTypeChanging(value);
                        this.SendPropertyChanging();
                        this._TemplateType = value;
                        this.SendPropertyChanged("TemplateType");
                        this.OnTemplateTypeChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

This one not:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Job")]
    [global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute()]
    public partial class Job : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="TemplateTypeCd", Storage="_TemplateType", DbType="TinyInt", CanBeNull=true, UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
                [global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(Order=20)]
                [GeneratedCodeAttribute("SqlMetal", "")]
                public global::Common.JobTemplateType? TemplateType
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return this._TemplateType;
                    }
                    set
                    {
                        if ((this._TemplateType != value))
                        {
                            this.OnTemplateTypeChanging(value);
                            this.SendPropertyChanging();
                            this._TemplateType = value;
                            this.SendPropertyChanged("TemplateType");
                            this.OnTemplateTypeChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: can you show how those types are defined in a .cs file of the original assembly source code?

Comment: Sure, I have edited the post

Comment: Ok, unfortunately the info even with what you included is not enough to repro the issue. Can you create a Minimal reproducible example of your issue, e.g. using .net fiddle? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Or at least give a complete code listing because you have a method to load assemblies, a method to load attributes on some types, and some json file you did not show. It is very confusing what is going on to tell you where your issue is

Comment: Jeah, sure, I can post all the code.
Should I append it as Edit?

Comment: Please do so, that's ideal. Please also take care to retain only relevant parts, specific to the issue.

Comment: Okay, I hope this is readable ;D 
Sorry, I'm not good at something like this it seems

Comment: Very close, can you add an example of ONE class with ONE property with this enum that is returned by `GetStreamDesignTypes` (that currently is not found)

Comment: Okay, I posted 2 examples. 
One that I get, one that I don't get.
It seems like it's just ignored by the getTypes() method. 
But I can't confirm really, because there are like 6k types and It's hard to search for one specific thing in all of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, reading your code i think the problem is here:

```
var property = propertyInfos
                .Where(p => p.PropertyType.FullName != null ? p.PropertyType.FullName.Equals(t.ToString(),
                                        StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) : false)
                .ToList();
```

**Update** Turns out I forgot Enums are value types, doh....

why not change it like so:

```
var property = propertyInfos
                .Where(p => p.PropertyType == t || 
                (t.IsValueType && p.PropertyType == typeof(System.Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(t))
                .ToList();
```

Comment: It's unfortunally the same result.
I get the two types without the "?" but the three types with "?" are still ignored :-(
But it look's much better, thank you